# use data() in result from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I tried to find a tag in the result from a ajax function and use data() to set value `'file', file_number` like below, but I can't see it in console.log, undefined is what i get.
is there something wrong with my code?

```
....success: function(html){
var result = $(html).filter('.result').html();
// console.log(result);
var file_number = $(html).find('.file_number').html();
// console.log(file_number); // will get number

// 
$(html).find('img').data('file', file_number); 
console.log($(html).find('img').data('file'));
```

Comment: What is the result of "console.log(file_number)" ?

Comment: You're trying to set data on non-DOM HTML elements?

Comment: @jmcollin92 number (string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there something wrong with my code?

Yes. You are calling `$(html)` multiple times, i.e. jQuery will parse the HTML string multiple times and create **different** DOM elements from it (each time). The changes you make to one of those parsed sets are not persistent and don't have any influence on any of the others.

Store the result of `$(html)` and only work on this **one set** of DOM elements:

```
var $html = $(html);
var result = $html.filter('.result').html();
// console.log(result);

var file_number = $html.find('.file_number').html();

$html.find('img').data('file', file_number); 
console.log($html.find('img').data('file'));
```